If $S$ is a discrete set of the open disk of $\mathbb{C}$, then the accumulation points of it has surface measure $0$
I need to prove this lemma for a specific assignment problem:
Let $S$ be a discrete set of the open disk $D = \{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1\}$ $($discrete in the sense that for any $x\in S$, there exists an open set of it that has empty intersection with other points of $S)$. Then the collection of accumulation points of $S$ has surface measure $0$. In other words, let $S_1$ be the collection of accumulation points of $S$, $S_1$ is a subset of the unit circle, and
$$
\{\theta\in\mathbb{R}: e^{i\theta}\in S_1\}
$$
has Lebesgue measure $0$.
My attempt is as follows:
It is sufficient to show that every point of $S_1$ is an isolated point. Then $S_1$ has finitely many points because the unit circle is compact, and $S_1$ has surface measure $0$.
However, I failed to show that every point of $S_1$ is an isolated point. Suppose that $x\in S_1$ is not an isolated point, it can be approached by a sequence $(x_n)$ in $S_1$, then for any point of $S$, we might still find a very small open ball of it which doesn't interact with other points of $S$. I failed to see why $x\in S_1$ not being an isolated point contradicts with the fact that $S$ is discrete.
Any help is welcome!

It is simply false that the accumulation set is necessarily contained in the unit circle. Accordingly, it is (in general) false that it has zero 2-dimensional measure. And, of course, it is (in general) false that every point of $S_1$ is isolated.

The result is actually not true - just take on the circle of radius $1-1/2^n$ all the roots of unity of order $2^n$ (times the radius); this set is clearly discrete and accumulates everywhere on the unit circle

@Conrad by saying of order $2^n$ do you mean the primitive $2^n$-th roots of unity?

No, all $2^n$ roots of unity of order $2^n$ - scaled down to modulus $1-1/2^n$;
